# MVC4 Bundling Strategy

Tags: optimization, asp.net-mvc-4, minify

I'm using the new Bundling feature in ASP.NET MVC4. Currently I have the following bundles configured:

- ~/js/jquery
- ~/js/forms
- ˜/js/bootstrap

Depending on the view I'm serving I usually call a combination of these three (e.g. the home page on needs the jquery bundle, while the contact page needs jquery + bootstrap, while forms need all three).

My question would be: is there a way to call the three bundles to be rendered as one file from the view? I don't want to make bundles for every possible combination:

- ˜/js/formsAndBootstrap
- ˜/js/formsAndJQueryAndBootstrap
- And so on...

Comment: You can define bundles much easier (in my opinion) using RxLoader https://nuget.org/packages/RxLoader/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you have to define a bundle. It can't be done "on-the-fly" from the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/formsAndBootstrap").Include(
                             "~/Content/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js",
                             "~/Content/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                             "~/Content/Scripts/form.js"))
```

Comment: This would mean I have to define a new bundle for each combination. If I have a defined bundle called "jQuery" and another one called "jQueryUI" and want to render them both as a single file, does it mean I have to make another bundle? can't I define one on the run from the view I'm calling it?